# How to find the centerpoint of a circle that intersects two points where the centerpoint is on the X axis

Tags: trigonometry

So say I have two points

(0, 5) and (-10, 0)

I want to find the centerpoint of a circle that intersects these two points...

With the additional requirement that the Y component is 0 and the X component is negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $h$ be the x-coordinate of the center of the circle. If you draw a picture, then you will see that the radius of the circle is then $h-(-10) = h+10$. On the other hand the radius of the cicle is also the distance from the center to the point $(0,5)$, which is $\sqrt{(h-0)^2 + (0-5)^2}$.

You can set these equal to each other and solve for $h$.